# click event not working inside div when v-html used - vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have one `contenteditable` `div` and adding raw html including a click event using `v-html`. But the click event is not working in this case. Inspecting elements shows there's a click event on the div but still it won't work.

If I hard code any other div with click event inside `contenteditable` `div` then it's working. Don't know if I am doing it right.
:

```
<div id="div_textarea2" v-html="temp_testing_div2" contenteditable="true"></div>


   data () {
    return {
          temp_testing_div2: `<div @click="ClickLine">Click this</div>`,

}
}


   ClickLine(){
   alert("Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

@HermantSah `v-html` won't bind any Vue directives such as `@click` events. See docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

A workaround could be to have the `@click` event on the parent div and in your template string give the element something distinguishable, like an id.
You could then intercept the event and check which element was clicked. If the element matches the one in your template string do something etc. A rough example below.

```
<div id="div_textarea2" v-html="temp_testing_div2" @click="handleLineClick" contenteditable="true"></div>

...  
// in your script section
data() {
  return {
    temp_testing_div2: `<div id="temp_testing_div2">Click this</div>`,
  }
},
methods: {
  handleLineClick(e) {
    let clickedElId = e.target.id
    if (clickedElId === 'temp_testing_div2') {
      console.log("temp_testing_div2 clicked!", e)
    } else {
      console.log('another element was clicked')
    }
  }
}
```

It all feels a little messy though in my opinion. There may be an easier way of achieving what you desire.

Comment: I think this won't work for me... These are requirements from business people. I have to show some suggested lines which will be in grey color first. if clicked it will turn into black . This all should happen inside textarea. Something similar to what gmail do...when we presses nav key, it auto completes.

Comment: If it's just changing the styling of elements as they're clicked you can definitely do that by starting with my example above. You can get a reference to the clicked element and then add a class to it or modify its styling directly

Comment: ok let me give a try.

Comment: Hi, Will your code work for dynamic data? you are checking only hardcoded id's..